# PHP - Column count doesn't match

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently trying to add data into a database, (New to php), I've looked over what other people has with this error but yet still I cannot see where I have gone wrong.
The error is:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Code:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'evocityi_admin';
$dbpass = 'password';
$database = 'evocityi_stocks';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


    $Dtime = "30/04/16";
    $StockName = "FUMUKU";
    $FUMUKUPrice = 1000;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO stocks".
           "(Stock,Price, TimeD) ".
           "VALUES ".
           "('$StockName,$FUMUKUPrice, $DTime')";
    mysql_select_db('evocityi_stocks');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

SQL Database:
https://gyazo.com/e74a6b9e87c18d60855424dcae647cdf

Comment: `$Dtime` not equal to `$DTime`

Comment: You really shouldn`t use mysql_connect and other mysql functions in PHP anymore since they are removed in PHP 7.0, rather replace them with mysqli equivalent, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the column type for Stock and TimeD to varchar in your table definition. On the link you posted, they are both int.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by @PaulB12345, change column type to varchar and there is error in quotes.

ideally your query should be like (see quotes after values)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stocks".
           "(Stock,Price, TimeD) ".
           "VALUES ".
           "('$StockName','$FUMUKUPrice', '$DTime')";
```